Can't install PyQt5 using pip on py3.11-slim docker
I am trying to install my requirements.txt and get this error for the PyQt5 package:
Downloading PyQt5-5.15.11.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
13.89      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 12.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
14.11   Installing build dependencies: started
17.20   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
17.20   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
17.27   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
17.27   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
17.35   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
17.35   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
17.35
17.35   × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
17.35   │ exit code: 1
17.35   ╰─> [25 lines of output]
17.35       Traceback (most recent call last):
17.35         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
17.35           main()
17.35         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
17.35           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
17.35                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
17.35         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
17.35           whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
17.35                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hv37guj9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 28, in build_wheel
17.35           project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
17.35                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hv37guj9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 74, in bootstrap
17.35           project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hv37guj9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 608, in setup
17.35           self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-install-j7nyano1/pyqt5_97df441236c2455f8e00d2a46e50d464/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
17.35           super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hv37guj9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
17.35           super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hv37guj9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
17.35           self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
17.35         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hv37guj9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
17.35           raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
17.35       sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
17.35       [end of output]
17.35
17.35   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
18.19 error: metadata-generation-failed
18.19
18.19 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
18.19 ╰─> See above for output.
18.19
18.19 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
18.19 hint: See above for details.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

My Dockerfile looks like this:
# app/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    software-properties-common \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY .config/requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
...

I tried some solution ideas like Can't install PyQt5 using pip on alpine docker or https://github.com/P0cL4bs/wifipumpkin3/issues/44 but nothing has helped.
Perhaps anyone knows the issue?
